# How can you have two copies of same package that cannot be used for having different namespaces

Tags: go

Here is a quote from a blog post:

> ### Enforce vanity URLs go get supports getting packages by a URL that is
>
> different than the URL of the package's repo. These URLs are called
>   vanity URLs and require you to serve a page with specific meta tags
>   the Go tools recognize. You can serve a package with a custom domain
>   and path using vanity URLs.
>
> For example,
>
> `$ go get cloud.google.com/go/datastore`
>
> checks out the source code from
>   https://code.googlesource.com/gocloud behind the scenes and puts it in
>   your workspace under $GOPATH/src/cloud.google.com/go/datastore.
>
> Given code.googlesource.com/gocloud is already serving this package,
>   would it be possible to go get the package from that URL? The answer
>   is no, if you enforce the vanity URL.
>
> To do that, add an import statement to the package. The go tool will
>   reject any import of this package from any other path and will display
>   a friendly error to the user. If you don't enforce your vanity URLs,
>   there will be two copies of your package that cannot work together due
>   to the different namespace.
>
> `package datastore // import "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"`

Can someone explain what the last line means?

> If you don't enforce your vanity URLs,
>   there will be two copies of your package that cannot work together due
>   to the different namespace.

Or demonstrate it in an example?

Comment: Types with different import paths are different types, regardless of whether they have identical source code. This ins't really a concern any longer with go modules, since the module name defines the import path.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple.

If your package is hosted at, say `github.com/foo/bar`, and you have vanity URL `foo.com/bar`, then someone could do both:

```
import "github.com/foo/bar"
```

and

```
import "foo.com/bar"
```

This will be problematic if you have different files or packages that import the same package at different paths.

Imagine these two files in the same package:

```
// foo.go
package foo

import "github.com/foo/bar"

func frobnicate(x *bar.Something) { /* ... */ }
```

```
// bar.go
package foo

import "foo.com/bar"

func widget() {
    x := *bar.Something{}
    frobnicate(x) // compilation error: cannot use x (type foo.com/bar.Something) as type github.com/foo/bar.Something
}
```